# 2d texture to a 3d item?

Tags: three.js, minecraft

I want to do what they do in Minecraft and that is take a 2d item and make a it 3d.

This:
[image]

to this:
[image]

Anyone have idea how I would do this without making a model in a seperate program

Comment: If your goal is to render something Minecraft style, why not take a look at Minecraft's source code?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you have proper images with a nice contrast to the background, you could try to read the image's pixel value and contrast and try to find the outline of those images. As a next step, you would use Three.Shape or Three.Path and trace the outline with LineTo. Afterwards, you use an ExtrudeGeometry and extrude the shape into a 3d-object.

The main problem is finding the outline, i guess. This would only work with proper images and depending on the quality you want to achieve, you will have to implement the proper algorithms, see edge detection filters maybe.

Or being very simplistic, read the pixel values, if they are white or close to white, ignore them and if they are not, Draw another line.... something like that...

Comment: This doesn't seem like a viable solution it would be mush easier to just make the model in blender or silo.

Comment: Well, THAT was your question! I was just adding some idea on how you could achieve this. Also, it would not be too hard and if done right, you could throw a lot of images on your algorithm and have it create pixelated, extruded objects for you. Anyway, your question involved not using a separate program to model this stuff. So don't say that it would be easier to model it in blender or silo.